# New soldering iron turns black as soon as it reaches 350C

Tags: soldering

I can't even tin it as it turns black befor I reach melting temperature. I tried 6 different tips and result is the same - it turns black and solder doesn't stick, I've no Idea what to do at this point also it smokes when reaches about 350C.

Is it just broken soldering iron and I need to buy a better one or I don't understand something?

I only tried Eutectic Solder, 5 tip were from same source 1 from other. I don't know brands.

Soldering iron is one of those cheep chinese variable temperature ones

Here's photo of it 
[image]

Comment: Hello vadimuha. (1) What is your question? You have not posed a question either in your title or in the body of your posting. Are you asking why the tips are failing? Are you asking how to prevent the tips burning? (2) Which brand of soldering iron and tips are you using? (3) Are you intending to work with eutectic (Sn-Pb) or lead-free solder? Please EDIT your question and add these details, do not post them as comments. Possible related question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27297/are-some-soldering-iron-tips-unsuitable-for-lead-free-solder

Comment: Did you try a different solder? Are all the tips from the same source? A sharp photo might be helpful.

Comment: This sounds like either the temperature regulator has failed, or the tips are not properly plated and the iron / steel later is uncoated and immediately rusting. Also your photo link is not working, please just embed it in your question

Comment: Buy a small jar of *tip tinner*. It may help.

Comment: Are you able to measure the actual temperature the tip is getting to? If the regulator has failed, the tip may be heating well beyond where it's supposed to, which would be easy to detect with an infrared thermometer or similar.

Comment: In your photo, looks like a blob of brown flux sits on the white desk, amongst solder tailings. Perhaps your solder has no flux core? For electronic work, we often use solder containing a rosin flux, especially if solder is of tin-lead type. This solder melts at lower temperatures than tin-only solder, and the added flux makes tip-tinning much, much easier.

Comment: It's a good question and I'm sure plenty of newbies have this problem, but it must have been posted before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't even tin it as it turns black before I reach melting
>   temperature.

What kind of solder is that?!

The highest melting point of the eutectic solder I have ever seen was around 300°C. Most of the commonly used solders melt way under 250°C. No wonder your iron tip turns black.

This is not to say there are no solders that need higher temperature, only that it is highly unlikely you'd ever need one.

Another possible reason for tip turning black is using plumbing solder or flux.

Comment: It's possible, I bought no name brand from a market, it's 63% solder. https://imgur.com/3RBg3fi

Comment: @vadimuha throw that thing out, and get some better solder. I have no idea what's inside it, but it's horrible.